# print all the list elements with an even index number, error statement

Tags: python, list, if-statement

for my task, which I think I have already right, but on Snakify it shows me this error statement: Traceback (most recent call last): ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3 4 5'
On google colab this error doesn't show up, on snakify it does, but I need this error to go so I can check my solutions. Any suggestions?

Task is: a list of numbers, find and print all the list elements with an even index number.

```
a = []
b = []

numbers = input()
for n in numbers.split():
    a.append(int(n))

    if int(n) % 2 == 0:
      b.append(a[int(n)])

print(b)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int()` can convert only numbers and raise error if argument contain a non-digit char, for example space ' '. You can use:

```py
nums = input().split()  # split() method splited string by spaces
a = []
for i in range(len(nums)):  # len() function return count of list elements
    if (i % 2) == 0:
        a.append(nums[i])

print(a)
```

Also you can get
`IndexError: list index out of range`
Please comment if interesting why

Answer (score 0):

`int(input())` will only work on a single number.  If you want to enter many numbers at once, you'll have to call `input()` first, split it into separate numbers, and call `int()` on each one:

```
numbers = input()
for n in numbers.split():
    a.append(int(n))
```

Or using a list comprehension:

```
numbers = input()
a = [int(n) for n in numbers.split()]
```

Comment: or theoretically even shorter: `a = [int(n) for n in input().split()]`, unless `numbers` has to be used some time later

Comment: may you check my edit? I think I make this more complicated than it is, it only allows me to input 1 number and then it shows []

Comment: @jfnotk please don't change your original question so much. now this answer is not an answer to your question any more.

Comment: Is this able to get all `even` index numbers?